# Reference handler object from main activity

Tags: java, android, handler

I have main an `Activity` class, a broadcast class ( subclass of broadcast receiver ) and few other classes. I use a `Handler` created in the broadcast class, for some things to do in future. But if some circumstances come ( user wants to exit app ), i want that `Handler` to cancel (prevent from being executed ).

I read a lot of threads in SO on how to cancel `Handlers` and I know how to from same class ( `Handler.removeCallback (Runnable )`, `Handler.removeMessages(0)` etc ). But I don't know how to cancel it from my `Activity`. ( user presses exit button, and if handler is going to do some work i want to prevent that ).

So how do I reference that handler object (which is going to execute ) from the `Activity` class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, however, if you want to cancel the `Handler` via an activity, you can put it in the `onPause` method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

The `onPause` method is called when an activity is about to be hidden from the user.

Having re-read your question, if you mean that you want to access the handler inside a `BroadcastReceiver` class from your `Activity` class, then you should make the handler a member variable of your activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public class BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
            // ... use mHandler in here ....
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }

    }

    // ... rest of the code ...

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

}
```

You can use the handler inside your `BroadcastReceiver` and `Activity` class using `mHandler`. You have to make sure that your `BroadcastReceiver` class is **not** a `static` inner class of the `Activity`.